# UISlider animation duration

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

Im new to swift and I'm trying to create an app where a slider moves back and forth form a value of 1- 100 for 60 second by pressing a button.However,I am not sure how to make the slider move smoothly from 1-100.This is my code so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var timer: UILabel!

var county = 5    
    @IBAction func animateSlider(sender: AnyObject) {if (county == 59){

        _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)}

    if (county>0){
    Slider.setValue(100, animated: true)


    }
```

The Problem? The UISlider value instantly moves from 1-100.So, how do I slow down this animation to 5 seconds or so?

Im aware of a similar thread but i'm new to Swift and I believe the other thread is written in Objective-C.Thus,I would love if anyone could help me explain in terms of swift.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894516/animate-uislider-smoothly

Answer (score 0):

```
    @IBAction func uiSliderShowProgress(sender: UISlider) {
if sender.value == 100 {
    var transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.startProgress = 0
    transition.endProgress = 1.0
    transition.duration = 0.8
    uiSliderShowProgress.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: "transition")
    uiSliderShowProgress.value = 0
    lblSliderProgress.text = "\(Int(uiSliderShowProgress.value))"
}
else {
    var transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.startProgress = 0
    transition.endProgress = 1.0
    transition.duration = 0.8
    uiSliderShowProgress.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: "transition")
    uiSliderShowProgress.value = 100
    lblSliderProgress.text = "\(Int(uiSliderShowProgress.value))"
}
}

@IBAction func btnChangeSliderValueClick(sender: UIButton) {
    self.uiSliderShowProgress(uiSliderShowProgress)
}
```

This changes the value of slider from 0-100 and 100-0 on buttons click and makes the thumb of the slider fade in and out, creating an illusion of being delayed!!! Hope this will help you...

Comment: yes but this moves the slider instantly from 1 - 100 just like slider.setValue(Int,animate: Bool).Is there any way to make it transition smoothly for 2 seconds from 1 - 100?

Comment: Hello I considered your problem and was finding a solution to it as it even made me very curious... what i found is using timers and UIView animations is not gonna work. So we can create a illusion instead of making it delay! i'm editing my answer with the code where i'm using CATransition animation which will make the sliders thumb to fade in and out to create an illusion that its being delayed...... I hope it will help you

Comment: Hi, yes I was looking for a way that timers and UIView animations were going to work.Tried out what you said and have to admit it is a nice effect.Thanks

Comment: @Chunks You are most welcome and m feeling grateful for being able to help you :)

Comment: @Chunks please accept it as an answer if it helped you :)